# Where exactly was the bullock killed in Exodus 29:11?

Tags: exodus, torah, tabernacle

Where exactly was the bullock killed in Exodus 29:11?

> And thou shalt kill the bullock before the Lord, *by the door* of the tabernacle of the congregation.

So: was it between the door of the tent itself (the Holy Place) and the laver, between the laver and the brazen altar, or, notwithstanding, between the brazen altar and the "bigger" entrance gate? I've put a red mark between the laver and the brazen altar because (it seems to me) killing the animal between the door of the Holy Place (*door* in the picture) and the laver wouldn't make sense at all.
Have I marked it correctly?

[image]

Comment: Related answer [in connection to sun worship](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/69973/21426)

Answer (score 0):

Stopping with the one verse leaves the situation unclear; context (as usual) helps:

> and shall take part of the blood of the bull and put it on the horns
> of the altar with your finger, and the rest of the blood you shall
> pour out at the base of the altar. And you shall take all the fat that
> covers the entrails, and the long lobe of the liver, and the two
> kidneys with the fat that is on them, and burn them on the altar.

Carrying out these instructions would be clumsy if the bull's carcass is right in front of the tent, but straightforward if between the laver and the altar of burnt offering.  This is especially true of lifting the specified parts of the carcass.

While this is not conclusive, it does make sense of the actions to be carried out.